# adding quotes to javascript array list in which each element is in a quote like below

Tags: arrays, quotes

How do I change this array list:

```
var array1 = ["test, test1"];
```

to show like below:

```
var array2 = ["test", "test1"]
```

Comment: Where are you getting the array from?

Comment: I am passing it as strings into database using 'in' operator as user select a list. but it comes out like ['a, b'] which the field in the database is not accepting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split it and insert into array as shown in the snippet.

```js
var array1 = ["test, test1"];

 var array = array1[0].split(',');
array = array.map(i => '"' + i + '"');
alert(array)
```

Comment: @olayinka If it does work and helped you, please mark the answer right

Answer (score 0):

Separate the string by commas, and use trim to get rid of any unwanted white-space.

```
var words = array1[0].split(",")
var array2 = []
for (var word in words){
  array2.push('"'+word.trim()+'"')
```